# ServletContainerInitializer ignored by Tomee because of jar name and web-fragment "ordering"

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, apache-tomee, web-fragment

The library I'm maintaining contains a implementation of `ServletContainerInitializer` which is declared in `META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer` file.

This library is used by web applications running on Tomee 8 (Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/9.0.63 (8.0.12)).

Recently I added the `log4j-web` dependency to the project. Before that my initializer was called as expected but since it is ignored.

After creating a minimal example I identified that my jar is ignored because :

- Its name starts with `spring-` (it is not a library of the Spring Framework, only a poor naming choice) and,
- Another jar in the classpath (log4j-web) contains a `web-fragment.xml` with "ordering" before or after "others" :

```xml
    <web-fragment xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                                      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-fragment_3_0.xsd"
                  version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">
    
        <name>my_web_fragment_xxx</name>
        <distributable />
        <ordering>
            <before>
                <others />
            </before>
        </ordering>
    </web-fragment>
```

I activated Tomcat traces logs and noticed that "spring" is listed in some exclusion prefixes as well as many other names.

```
    TRACE [Thread-2] org.apache.openejb.config.NewLoaderLogic.readDefaultExclusions Loaded default.exclusions
    TRACE [Thread-2] org.apache.openejb.config.NewLoaderLogic.logExclusions Exclusion prefixes: [
    ...
    TRACE [Thread-2] org.apache.openejb.config.NewLoaderLogic.logExclusions -snappy-java-
    TRACE [Thread-2] org.apache.openejb.config.NewLoaderLogic.logExclusions -spring-
    TRACE [Thread-2] org.apache.openejb.config.NewLoaderLogic.logExclusions -sshd-
    ...
```

I noticed that "google" is listed too and when I prefix my jar with "google-" it reproduces the same issue.

The default exclusion list comes from `openejb-core` library :
https://github.com/apache/tomee/blob/c0928e2aed1713d16d28bffaed11ad5024bc3728/container/openejb-core/src/main/resources/default.exclusions

### Workarounds

- Rename the library (but it will have an impact on applications depending on it),
- Add the name of the ignored jar to the `tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToScan` jars list (but it has to be done to every environments from dev to production for customers using our products).

### Question

What I would like to understand is, why this issue is only triggered when a jar in the classpath contains a *web-fragment* with an `<ordering>` element ?

### Minimal reproducible sample

https://github.com/KWSimon/tomcat_jarscanning

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Would you mind creating an issue at jira.apache.org?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I created a bug: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66129

Comment: Needs to be TomEE, not Tomcat  :)

Comment: I created it in Tomee too now ... https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMEE-3982
I hope I got it right this time and will stop spamming everyone with this issue ...